# Javascript, add varying separators to a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, split

very new to coding so sorry if my vocabulary is off.
This is the exact requirements for the function I'm trying to achieve:

If a word is five or more letters long, add “-bork” to the end of the word

If a word is less than five letters long, add “-boink” to the end of the word

For example: “The quick brown fox” becomes “The-boink quick-bork brown-bork fox-boink"

This is what I have so far...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var string = prompt("Enter a string");
      var array = string.split(" ");
      var length = array.map(function (word) {
        return word.length;
      });
      var langauge = array.join("-bork ");
      alert(langauge);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this.

```js
var string = "The quick brown fox";
var array = string.split(" ");
var langauge = array.map(function(word) {
  return word.length < 5 ? `${word}-boink` : `${word}-bork`;
}).join(" ");
alert(langauge);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map the words with the suffix and join the array for getting a string.

```js
function append(string) {
    return string
        .split(' ')
        .map(s => s + (s.length < 5 ? '-boink' : '-bork'))
        .join(' ');
}

console.log(append('The quick brown fox'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `String.split`, `Array.join` and `Array.map`.

```js
const input = 'The quick brown fox';
const output = input.split(' ').map(item => item.length >= 5 ? item.concat('-bork') : item.concat('-boink')).join(' ');

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var string = prompt("Enter a string");
  var array = string.split(" ");
  var newArr = array.map(function (word) {
  return word+"-"+(word.length>=5?"bork":"boink")
  });
  var langauge = newArr.join(" ");
  alert(langauge);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var string = prompt("Enter a string");
      var array = string.split(" ");
      var length = array.map(function (word) {
      var langauge;
        console.log(word.length)
        if(word.length>=5)
        {
            langauge=word+"-bork"
            return langauge
        }
        else
        {
            langauge=word+"-boink"
            return langauge
        }
        
      });
      var finalword= length.join(" ");
      alert(finalword);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

[image]